# vscode shows error in JSX attribute name that has colon

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

In my JSX code I have attribute name that has colon in its name but vscode shows error. Even after formatting my code, vscode automatically create a space after colon. How to solve these two problems?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By not having colon in your attribute name. While technically possible, attribute names should be camelCase.

If you can't get around this, you could create and object and destructure it onto props.

```
const A = () => {
    const fooProps = {
        'on:resize': onResize
    }

    return <Foo {...fooProps} />
}
```